# Access HP Helion from Apache Brooklyn

Tags: apache, jclouds, brooklyn

I want to access HP Helion cloud using Apache Brooklyn project.
With the help of the link [Access HP Helion using jclouds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351307/how-can-i-access-hp-helion-using-apache-jclouds), 
 I am able to launch an instance but deployment at Brooklyn fails with the following error :

> Error invoking start at EmptySoftwareProcessImpl{id=nkJ0UYV4}: org.jclouds.compute.RunNodesException: error running 1 node group(brooklyn-guvb-ubuntu-simple-vm-c7zq-vm-nkj0) location(region-a.geo-1) image(43804523-7e3b-4adf-b6df-9d11d451c463) size(100) options({scriptPresent=true, userMetadata={Name=brooklyn-guvb-ubuntu-simple-vm-c7zq-vm-nkj0-qqjs, brooklyn-user=ubuntu, brooklyn-app-id=c7ZQXESh, brooklyn-app-name=simple-vm, brooklyn-entity-id=nkJ0UYV4, brooklyn-entity-name=VM, brooklyn-server-creation-date=2015-09-01-0503}, generateKeyPair=true, configDrive=false})
>   Execution failures:
>   1) ExecutionException on brooklyn-guvb-ubuntu-simple-vm-c7zq-vm-nkj0-f0c:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: command: POST https://region-a.geo-1.compute.hpcloudsvc.com/v2/............/servers/12bc827b-16e6-4616-b75d-e001693eb65a/action HTTP/1.1 failed with response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request; content: [{"badRequest": {"message": "No nw_info cache associated with instance", "code": 400}}]

I can see in Helion that instances get created but no IP is assigned for instances and no network is associated with them.

Can anyone help me with this ?

-Thanks

Comment: Hi @user3796119, can you post your brooklyn.properties for this particular location (minus sensible information of course) as well as the YAMl your are trying to deploy?

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351307/how-can-i-access-hp-helion-using-apache-jclouds?lq=1)

Comment: Hi @ThomasBouron , My brooklyn.properties file is here: http://pastebin.com/xymGFh99. I referred to (https://github.com/apache/incubator-brooklyn/blob/9595ddc943fa9cb00f86a20e030cffd07bded69b/locations/jclouds/src/main/resources/brooklyn/location-metadata.properties) and  (https://community.hpcloud.com/question/2268/jclouds-api-not-working)

Comment: @grkvlt, I created a network explicitly and provided uuid in blueprint. Now , the instance gets created correctly, it gets an IP from the network that I have mentioned also but the brooklyn application gets stuck in VM creation stage (provision stage ). Blueprint : http://pastebin.com/VS99wKX1. Can you please help?

Comment: @ThomasBouron, Blueprint :  pastebin.com/VS99wKX1. Can you please help?

Comment: Hi @user3796119, based on your blueprint / configuration, the location within your blueprint is wrong. Can you try that: `location: hpcloud-east`?

Comment: Hi @ThomasBouron, If I replace location to **location: hpcloud-east** , I get the error `Illegal parameter for 'location' (hpcloud-east); not resolvable: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unknown location 'hpcloud-east': either this location is not recognised or there is a problem with location resolver configuration` .

Comment: hi @ThomasBouron. Please ignore the above comment, it was a mistake from my side and I corrected it . I tried **location: hpcloud-east**. Blueprint :  http://pastebin.com/pjDWDSHM . I  am getting the error `org.jclouds.rest.AuthorizationException....: Exhausted available authentication methods`. The instance gets created successfully and the security group created beforehand has port 22 open but brooklyn app gets on fire.  Is there anything that is missing ? .

Comment: Can you SSH to the machine? If yes, check if there is any iptables rules in place. If there are, you might want to disable it by adding `brooklyn.location.named.hpcloud-east.stopIptables=true` within your `brooklyn.properties`

Comment: Hi @ThomasBouron, Now the app is not getting on fire but I was not able to ssh into it. I tried providing my keypair in provisioning.properties. But I cannot see the keypair getting associated with instance. Blueprint I tried [link] (http://pastebin.com/7EbZETpv) . I have provided the private key path in brooklyn.properties. I tried overriding the private key by providing `loginUser.privateKeyFile` option in blueprint but I get an error `no credential or ssh agent found for username on node ..`. It looks like Brooklyn is not picking up the  private key at all. Any help ?